# An application of Ito's formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I am reading a proof in which I don't understand how to use Ito's rule to derive the following:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space such that $M^{(i)}$ and $M^{(k)}$ are continuous local martingales null at $0$. Let $b_i, b_k : [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel-measurable maps and let $X$ be a process taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then it claims that
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> && \int_0^t (M^{(i)}_s - M^{(i)}_t) b_k (s, X_s) \,ds +  \int_0^t (M^{(k)}_s - M^{(k)}_t) b_i (s, X_s) \,ds \\
> &= & - \int_0^t \bigg[ \int_0^s b_k (u,X_u) \,du \bigg] \, dM^{(i)}_s -\int_0^t \bigg[ \int_0^s b_i (u,X_u) \,du \bigg] \, dM^{(k)}_s.
> \end{eqnarray}

Any idea of how to show this? The book claims that it requires an application of Ito's formula but I do not know what expression should I apply it to.

Comment: To me it looks like an application of stochastic Fubini... since $$M_s^{(i)}-M_t^{(i)} = - \int_s^t dM_u^{(i)}$$ we have $$\int_0^t (M_s^{(i)}-M_t^{(i)}) b_k(s,X_s) \, ds = - \int_0^t b_k(s,X_s) \int_s^t dM_u^{(i)} \, ds.$$ Now if we formally (!) interchange the integrals we get $$\int_0^t (M_s^{(i)}-M_t^{(i)}) b_k(s,X_s) \, ds  = - \int_0^t \left( \int_0^u b_k(s,X_s) \, ds \right) \, dM_u^{(i)}.$$

Comment: @saz Is there any sufficient condition needed to apply the Stochastic Fubini theorem??

Comment: @saz This equality comes from a proof for a theorem concerning the Stroock and Varadhan martingale problem from "Brownian motion and Stochastic Calculus", by Karatzas and Shreve. I suppose that it is absolutely rigorous?

Comment: Yeah, sure; it requires proper integrability and measurability... I'm not an expert in Stochastic Fubini; it's just what came to my mind when I saw the equality.